# Using javascript append to move multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a wordpress plugin that creates a slider in a output order like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="">
        <div class="wp1s-caption-wrapper">
            <div class="wp1s-caption-title">
            <div class="wp1s-caption-content">
    </li>
    <!-- each slide as this same setup within the li, currently I have three slide so therefore 3 sets of the above li-->
</ul>
```

Now what I need to do is enter a div (hh-caption) into the div class wp1s-caption-wrapper and then insert wp1s-caption-title and wp1s-caption-content inside that. To do this I though to use append like so:

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j(document).ready(function(){
    j(".wp1s-caption-wrapper").append(j(".hh-caption"));
    j(".hh-caption").append(j(".wp1s-caption-title"));
    j(".hh-caption").append(j(".wp1s-caption-content"));
});
```

Now this enters the div hh-caption into each of the `wp1s-caption-wrapper` divs, but it places every `wp1s-caption-title` and `wp1s-caption-content` that appears. I have three sliders with title and captions so what happens is each `hh-wrapper` contains 3 titles and captions. I only want the title and content directly above each `hh-caption` (append puts `hh-caption` below title and content) to move into it not all occurences.

I don't want to edit the plugins codedirectly as any updates would most likely require me to redo everything, I though doing it with javascript in my own pages would be easier to alter if updates changed anything.

Does anyone have any suggestions or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Need more HTML to help. The HTML you have is also not valid. You could possibly use nth-child to match them up if they are in the same order in the DOM, but it's not possible to know with the html snippet you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

I have not really understood what you are trying to do but to my understanding I will ask you to try appendTo instead of append

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j(document).ready(function(){

    j(j('.hh-caption').appendTo('.wp1s-caption-wrapper');

   j(j('.wp1s-caption-title').appendTo('.hh-caption');

});
```

Comment: Yeah its quite hard to explain. I have multi lists (li) each with a title div content div. I want to add another div to each li and put each title and content from that indivdual li in it. but what happned is all the title and contents from all the lists (li) get put in each new div

Comment: this link might help you , there are couple of examples matching your case.. http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, I think your issue is you are selecting all the elements and then appending your new content. You need to specify the exact element you want to append to. Usually I would say use an `id` but I understand you don't want to change the existing code so instead you can do 2 things:

**One Append**: Append everything in one go, I prefer this as its less code, but depending on how complex the html is your adding, this may not be suited.

**Multiple Append**: Append the caption wrapper, then within that the title etc. This assumes you are always adding it to the end and uses jquery `.last()`

I hope this helps, sorry its a bit lengthy but wanted to demonstrate it well.

```js
$("#addCaption1").click(function() {
  captionImage = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1473182446278-fa0683411d10?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=1199&h=799&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=";
  captionTitle = "This is a new caption";
  captionContent = "This caption was added via jquery.";
  addCaption1(captionImage, captionTitle, captionContent);

});

$("#addCaption2").click(function() {
  captionImage = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1462834026679-7c03bf571a67?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=1199&h=791&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=";
  captionTitle = "This is a new caption";
  captionContent = "This caption was added via jquery.";
  addCaption2(captionImage, captionTitle, captionContent);
});


function addCaption1(imgUrl, title, content) {
  var caption = '<li><img src=' + imgUrl + '><div class="wp1s-caption-wrapper"><div class="wp1s-caption-title"><strong>' + title + '</strong><div class="wp1s-caption-content"><p>' + content + '</p></div></div></div></li>';

  $("#sidebar").append(caption);
}

function addCaption2(imgUrl, title, content) {
  var captionWrapper = '<li><img src=' + imgUrl + '><div class="wp1s-caption-wrapper"></div></li>';
  $("#sidebar").append(captionWrapper);
  $(".wp1s-caption-wrapper").last().append('<div class="wp1s-caption-title"><strong>' + title + '</strong></div>');
  $(".wp1s-caption-wrapper").last().find(".wp1s-caption-title").append('<div class="wp1s-caption-content"><p>' + content + '</p>');
}
```

```css
button {
  padding: 5px;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #ccc;
  color: #333;
  width: 180px;
  display: inline-block;
}
li img {
  width: 180px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addCaption1">One append</button>
<button id="addCaption2">Multiple appends</button>
<ul id="sidebar">
  <!-- Item 1 -->
  <li>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1473220464492-452fb02e6221?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=1199&h=800&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=">
    <div class="wp1s-caption-wrapper">
      <div class="wp1s-caption-title"><strong>This is a title for Item 1</strong>
        <div class="wp1s-caption-content">
          <p>This is some content for Item 1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <!-- Item 2 -->
  <li>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1467791702337-32e58d17bb6d?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=1199&h=796&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=">
    <div class="wp1s-caption-wrapper">
      <div class="wp1s-caption-title"><strong>This is a title for Item 2</strong>
        <div class="wp1s-caption-content">
          <p>This is some content for Item 2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <!-- Item 3 -->
  <li>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1473496169904-658ba7c44d8a?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=1199&h=799&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=">
    <div class="wp1s-caption-wrapper">
      <div class="wp1s-caption-title"><strong>This is a title for Item 3</strong>
        <div class="wp1s-caption-content">
          <p>This is some content for Item 3</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I recommend running in full page.